# NSDateFormatter Does not convert correctly

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I have a NSString which is passed from an xml feed........

```
NSString *strDate =@"Thu, 22 Apr 2010 10.30 am CEST";
```

I'm currently using this code to format the date........

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a vvvv"];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]);
```

I want to format my string only to display only hours and currently I'm getting value like this.

```
strDate =@"2010-04-10 14:00:00 +0530";
```

Can anyone please help me with this?......

---

I'm sorry.It's my mistake.It should be like this.

```
NSString *strDate =@"Thu, 22 Apr 2010 10:30 am CEST";
```

What my requirement is to get hour part only from above string using NSDateFormatter. How can I achieve that. Sorry for the earlier mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the 10 of 10:30 (if its ur requirement) then you can do it like:

```
strDate = @"Thu, 22 Apr 2010 10:30 am CEST";
NSArray *dateComponents = [strDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *requiredString = [dateComponents objectAtIndex:4];
dateComponents = [requiredString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
requiredString = [dateComponents objectAtIndex:0];
```

and when you do:

```
NSLog(rquiredString);
```

**Output :** 10;

This is just a workaround, for better approach you should go through the **NSDateComponents class.**

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
NSString *strDate =@"Thu, 22 Apr 2010 10:30 am CEST";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh"];
strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
```

(Firstly your original formatter was wrong, you had a: instead of a .) EDIT no longer the case

Secondly, you want to ignore the CEST bit as this will cause your timezone being changed

Comment: Hi,

I'm sorry.It's my mistake.It should be like this.

NSString *strDate =@"Thu, 22 Apr 2010 10:30 am CEST";

Comment: What my requirement is to get hour part only from above string using NSDateFormatter. How can I achieve that. Sorry for the earlier mistake.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh.mm a vvvv"];
```

(. instead of : in hh:mm)

Comment: Hi,

I'm sorry.It's my mistake.It should be like this.

NSString *strDate =@"Thu, 22 Apr 2010 10:30 am CEST";

Comment: What my requirement is to get hour part only from above string using NSDateFormatter. How can I achieve that. Sorry for the earlier mistake.